# Error while installing mariadb-server on Kali Linux

Tags: apt, kali-linux, dpkg, mariadb

I'm starting to set up my first DVWA on my Kali Linux machine. I tried to install `mariadb-server` using `apt-get install mariadb-server` as a root. I ran into error and I couldn't proceed.

```
Preparing to unpack .../6-mariadb-client-10.3_1%3a10.3.23-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-client-10.3 (1:10.3.23-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-server-core-10.3.
Preparing to unpack .../7-mariadb-server-core-10.3_1%3a10.3.23-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-server-core-10.3 (1:10.3.23-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package rsync.
Preparing to unpack .../8-rsync_3.2.2-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rsync (3.2.2-2) ...
Setting up mariadb-common (1:10.3.23-1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-common (--configure):
 installed mariadb-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-common
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@kali:~#
```

I think the problem is with a broken dpkg package. I need more insight on this.

Answer (score 4):

Okay so according to the error, you are missing a file. What you can do is download and extract the package and insert the missing file and then resinstall the package.

First, download the package by running the following commands:

```
cd
mkdir mariadbcommon
cd mariadbcommon
apt-get download mariadb-common
```

Now, extract the files:

```
ar xvf *
tar xvf dat*
```

Then, copy the needed file to the proper location:

```
cp ./etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf
```

Finally, reinstall the package:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall mariadb-common
```

and for good measure, reinstall the original package:

```
apt-get install --reinstall mariadb-server
```

If you don't have a problem overwriting your system wide configuration files, you can run the following instead:

```
apt install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" mariadb-common
```

and

```
apt install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" mariadb-server
```

Please post any errors.

---

Additionally, when you have a missing file error, it helps to use `apt-file` to determine the package that contains the file. The following will walk you through the process used to solve your problem.

First, install apt-file:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
```

Now, to search for the package that contains the missing file `/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf` for example, run the following command:

```
apt-file search /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf
```

Next, download the package (deb file) using the `apt-get download` or `apt download` command to download the needed package.

Then, use the `ar xvf *` command to extract the deb file and then use the `tar xvf dat*` command to extract the " data.tar.xz" file which contains the system files.

Finally, copy the extracted file to the correct location using the `cp` command.